# C# WPF drawing component

Tags: c#, .net, drawing, components

I am looking for a drawing component (like OneNote) that I could use as a part of my WPF application without the need of programming it myself. Is there anything like that or I have to do it the hard way?

EDIT (some more info): The product is a smart-wall application that needs a simple whiteboard program, that would have some basic functions: pen, text, shape, insert picture, Load/Save with some functions to change attributes like colour and line thickness. And I am looking for a solution if there is any to just add it into my application and no bother to program it myself.

EDIT 2: I found only this: http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/DrawingBoard2-A-Net-GDI-drawing-component
but is seems that the content is already gone.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." Quoted from [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Agree with @maam27.  What have you tried already, or what have you "taken a liking to"?

Comment: It's true this isn't a real question , but i for one would like to ear any recommendations for such a tool .. 
where is the correct place to ask questions like this ?

Comment: @eranotzap this type of questions can't be awnsered, since the awnser would be a personal opinion and libraries change all the time.

Comment: @maam27 Don't get me wrong am not looking for a library that I could use, I am looking for some component, that already exists and could be used in WPF.